# Why does Ca(CH3CH2CH2COO)2 dissolve in HCl and not in NaOH?

Tags: acid-base

I do not understand why a strong base, such as NaOH would not dissolve a solid such as this. There would be a double displacement in which you form Ca(OH)2 and NaCH3CH2COO (aq).

Why would HCl dissolve this better?

Comment: Is it $\ce{CH3CH2COO-}$ like in the text, or $\ce{CH3CH2CH2COO-}$ like in the title?

Comment: At what temperature? Both are solids at room temperature.

Answer (score 2):

[Propionic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propionic_acid) is a liquid at room temperature and miscible with water.

[Sodium propionate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_propionate) only has a solubility of 1 gram per milliliter. It is common to "salt out" carboxylic acids by adding an alkali metal. I think potassium is more commonly used than sodium.

Calcium hydroxide is relatively insoluble in water, especially in NaOH with a $K_{sp} =5.5\times10^{−6}$. So any $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ freed from the calcium propionate would form a gelatinous mass around the rest of the calcium propionate thus sealing it off.

In HCl calcium propionate would yield calcium chloride and propionic acid, both of which are very soluble in water.

Comment: A solubility of $\pu{1 g/mL}$, or $\pu{1 kg/L}$, doesn't seem very small to me. Sodium chloride, which I consider as well soluble, only comes to $\pu{0.359 kg/L}$ according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_chloride).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - It is all relative.  Propionic acid is miscible with water. So relative to  propionic acid, sodium propionate has a lower solubility.